# In Django models, can I fetch the value of a field, process it and store it in another field?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to reference the value of a field in another field.
I've tried `default=self.key_name * 2`, but that won't work.

```py
class Pizza_size(models.Model):
    length = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=self.length*2)
```

When I create an object with the `Pizza_size` class, if the value of length is 5, I want the value of price to be 10 by just running the command `Pizza_size(length=5)`.

Comment: You can, but not with such `default=...`. That being said, if `price` is functional dependent on `length`, it is better not to store `price` at all.

Comment: Is price always length*2? If so you should just use a property

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you, but how can I if not with `default=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/), "A classic use-case for overriding the built-in methods is if you want something to happen whenever you save an object."

Given what it seems you are trying to accomplish, the correct way to handle this would be to override the save method for the model.

Here's an example:

```
class Pizza_size(models.Model):
    length = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price = self.length*2
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Another option would be to use the pre_save signal, but that is not as simple or standard as the above.